# Why is there a readonly page in between the data segment and BSS segment?

Tags: c, process, memory-address

The data segment is read writable and is located directly above the bss segment in the address space of a program. However my C program has one rw page of data segment, one page of read only memory, and then the rw pages of the bss segment. Why is there a read only page between the data and bss segments and how did it get there?

Comment: What platform is this?

Comment: It's probably the page containing the GOT under relro protection.